# MOQ: How to cast a Mock of an Interface back to the interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to write Unit Tests for a private method which expects an Interface (EnvDTE.Project).

I'm using the Moq Framework to create a Mock of this Interface:

```
Mock<Project> mock = new Mock<Project>();
```

After I'm setting the Properties, I want to cast this mock back to the Interface.
I'm trying this:

```
mock.As<Project>();                 //to implement the Project interface
Project project = mock as Project;  //this set Project to null
Project project = (Project)mock;    //this throws InvalidCastException
```

Is there another way to solve this Problem?

Comment: You don't create mocks of the classes themselves, but of the services that they depend upon. You then inject these dependencies usually via constructor injection.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why do you want to convert mocked object back to the interface? Isn't it working as expected without converting? Can you explain the specific use where you need to do this conversion? Also interfaces do not have private method. If the class implementing the interface have private method then it should be tested by Unit Testing of that particular class not via interface.

Comment: I try to test a private Method.

Comment: with PrivateObject.Invoke("MethodName", new object[] { MOCK (here i Need a Interface, cause i cannot use the Mock) };

Comment: @Desiigner - Is "Project" a service of some description. i.e. it returns data to a consuming class?

Comment: You don't need to test private method specifically. If you write proper unit tests of public methods of the class which are calling private method, covering all the logical flows the private method code is automatically tested. You can use code coverage tool to see which code is covered and not covered as part of unit testing. So if your class `Project` is having private method and is implementing interface `IProject` then you should write unit tests of `Project` class to cover the code of its private method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access your mocked object with:

```
var mock = new Mock<Project>(); 
Project project = mock.Object;
```

Comment: @Desiigner - How does this allow you to test a private method?

Comment: @Wheels73 with a PrivateObject of the class and then i Invoke the Method and use a object Array to define the Parameter.

Comment: I'm not trying to be clever.. but the whole purpose of mocking an object is because you don't want to invoke the concrete implementation. Doing whats listed above is the same as instancing the Project class and just calling the methods. When you mock an object, you call the Setup methods on the mock to say what input to expect and what output it is to give you. If your test goes through the lines of code in the mock object you've created, then that's not what its intended for.

Comment: I've added you an answer for reference anyway. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you do not need to mock out what you are doing.

Say we have a class called "Project".

```
public class Project
    {
        //Private method to test
        private bool VerifyAmount(double amount)
        {
            return (amount <= 1000);
        }
    }
```

We can then write a test using the PrivateObject approach you want to do.

```
[TestMethod]
public void VerifyAmountTest()
{
   //Using PrivateObject class
   PrivateObject privateHelperObject = new PrivateObject(typeof(Project));
   double amount = 500F;
   bool expected = true;
   bool actual;
   actual = (bool)privateHelperObject.Invoke("VerifyAmount", amount);

   Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual); 
 }
```

This will achieve what you want.

Comment: Yeah that works for normal unit tests but not for this one.